# Make epub programmatically in app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql, epub

I'm developing a web service in App Engine standard environment with Java (servlets).
The idea is that it get info. from Cloud SQL and generate a EPUB programmatically with Siegmann' epub library: http://www.siegmann.nl/epublib

But i'm not sure that how can add things like images or html files (i first will convert the info. from Cloud SQL to HTML), sicen the writer of epub needs a path to a files.

can i download first all resources that need in local directory of app engine and references them?
Or what can i do?

Thank you in advance and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1:**

You can use the `/tmp` directory of your App Engine instance to store temporary files. See this [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/runtime#filesystem_access).

Bear in mind that files stored in the `/tmp` folder will only be accessible within the instance that wrote them.

**Option 2:**

After a quick look to Siegmann' epub library, I have seen that resources [can be provided as Byte arrays](http://www.siegmann.nl/static/epublib/apidocs/nl/siegmann/epublib/domain/Resource.html#Resource(byte%5B%5D,%20nl.siegmann.epublib.domain.MediaType)) and the writer fills [an OutputStream](http://www.siegmann.nl/static/epublib/apidocs/nl/siegmann/epublib/epub/EpubWriter.html#EpubWriter(nl.siegmann.epublib.epub.BookProcessor)).

With this in mind, you could use Cloud Storage and it's Java Client Library to download and store the files.

In [this Java sample from the docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#java), you can see that an object is up laded without the need of it being stored in file-system, just passing it as Byte array.

And to download files from Cloud Storage into the memory of your App Engine App, you could use `storage.get(BlobId.of(bucketName, objectName)).getContent()` to get the object's byte array